# Enchanted Superior Impements

Tags: dnd-4e, equipment, implements

I was wondering if an enchantment on a weapon, specifically a Superior Implement, would override it's previous effect.

For example, I'm looking to use a *Quickbeam staff* (with the effects of being energized with thunder, and is a forceful weapon, allowing it to increase forced movement effects).  If I were to then put a *Thundering Weapon +1* enchantment on it (gives a daily power and more critical) would the *Thundering Weapon +1* enchantment override the effects of the the *Quickbeam Staff*?

Answer (score 5):

You continue to get the benefit of superior implements even if they are enchanted, so long as you have the Superior Implement Training feat for the appropriate type.

Considering it costs a feat to take advantage of, superior implements wouldn't be much use otherwise.

From PHB3 Page 195:

> Formed of exotic materials and created using magical crafting techniques, superior implements enhance a wielder's magic. Despite their magical origin, Superior Implements aren't magic items per se, but like non-superior implements. **they can be enchanted with the Enchant Magic Item ritual**.